# Inter-process Communication in UNIX

Tags: c++, c, unix

Is it possible to fork a process and have the parent process tell the forked process to call a function and return its results to the parent? If so, how can we accomplish this? I'm not sure if the best way to perform the inter-process communication is through pipes or sockets (or some other structure). I'm only interested in performing IPC on Unix-based systems and programming in C/C++.

Comment: Why don't you use a thread instead of a new process? Lightweight and easy communication with the parent thread.

Comment: I'm separating the processes to implement privilege separation between the parent and the child. Wouldn't two threads run with the same privileges?

Comment: Yes, all the threads from a process are part of the process, and OS privileges are based in processes. So you can't have different privileges for different threads of the same process.

Comment: Right. I should have mentioned that I am interested in doing this in the interest of privilege separation. The child process will be performing privileged operations on behalf of the parent. As such, I don't want the parent process to have transparent access to anything the child process does.

Comment: What, specifically, are the signature and semantics of the function you wish the child to invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a parent-child relationship, I think that unnamed pipes (AKA "pipes") are better. Otherwise, you can use local sockets or FIFOs (AKA "named pipes").

You can make the parent send an integer to the child. The child, based on the integer received, runs a certain function and sends back the result to the parent.

Comment: The parent will have to serialize the results of the function call, right? I've never done this in C/C++, but I've done it in Java.

Comment: No serialization. Just make the parent send an integer value (e.g., 2). On the child, use an if else: if (value_received == 2) f1(...); else if (value_received == 3) f2(...); and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "the child will have to serialize..." If the child is calling a function and needs to return the results to the parent process, then how could the child send the results to the parent without serialization? And how could the parent receive the results without deserialization?

Comment: How does serialization find its way into this?  If you mean the parent and child have to know in advance what structures need to be passed for the request and answer, then yes, they have to "serialized".

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. How can I perform serialization on the arguments to the function? And how can I deserialize the results?

Comment: Pretty much the same way you would call a function in the parent.  If you are asking the child to perform funcA() you need to coordinate something that means funcA() (e.g. int opcode = 3) followed by a write to the pipe of the relevant parameters for funcA. Obviously you can't pass pointers or references so things like strings will need to be prefixed with their length.  If you go too much beyond this you are basically reinventing RPC, Corba, etc.

Comment: Yes, you need to serialize/deserialize.  The easiest way (which only works for non-pointer types) is to convert your data into a `char` array by taking its address and casting to a `char *` and using `sizeof` to know how large it is.  If your data contains pointers, you'll need to use somethine like [google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)